# How do I update a D3 SVG chart based on user input

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I would like for a variable to update dynamically, based on user input. I have several data sets in a Json file and want to create a graph using the particular data set the user chooses.

In the example below, the variable "dataset" is statically set to food, but there are other data sets (drinks, silverware, etc.) that the user can choose from and would should alter the graph data.

But I can't figure out how to make "dataset" update dynamically. I want to keep "data.", but change "food" to whatever the user chooses. Is this possible?

```
var dataset = data.food;

var svg = d3.select ("body") 
  .append ("svg")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h); 
svg.selectAll("rect")
  .data(dataset)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this quite easily. Assuming that the variable `value` holds the name of the dataset, you can do

```
var dataset = data[value];
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked...can you tell me why? What do the brackets do, and why don't I need a period? I am still learning D3

Comment: foo["bar"] is equivalent to foo.bar. You might want to have a look at some Javascript tutorials :)